# Why xpath Changes for UILabel for UITableViewCell in Appium?

Tags: ios, testing, xpath, automation, appium

I have `UITableViewCell` which has Subject,Name,Description,time. When I am testing this on `Appium` the xpath changed for UIElement for Subject line only.
xpath:-subject line: `//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[3]**/UIAStaticText[2]**`

after changes 
xpath:-subject line: `//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[3]**/UIAStaticText[3]**`

Which is giving another UI element details, which fails the testing. How to handle this from Appium, or do I need to fix it from Xcode?

Comment: use cell.accessibilityIdentifier = "UNIQUE NAME FOR EACH CELL" in app.. using accessibilityIdentifier is the best and recommended from apple.. access the cells/uiviews/buttons/.. with  accessibilityIdentifier from appuim for automation..

Comment: if still you are looking for only xpath, search for the string text in all cells labels

Comment: I guess xpath is something else? accessibilityIdentifier we are setting.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on xpaths is not a really good idea. 
But sometimes it is the only way to develop your scripts if there are no static ids nor accessibility labels available.

Your element that was previously set as: `UIAStaticText[2]`, so as I suppose it was second element available at current screen. Now looks like `UIAStaticText[3]` - it is marked as third. If you are not able to see changes on the screen that you are automating, that can be caused because of an element that is under in the background it can be hidden.

The best approach will be with using static resource id's in your scripts or accessibility labels which you have mentioned in comment you've them already set and available.